# How can I change the installation directory to drive A?

Tags: technical-issues, diablo-iii

My friend is trying to install Diablo 3 in his windows 7. But he kind of messed up a little with his partitions.

All his files (and also extra space) are in the drive **A**, but his OS (windows 7) is running from drive **C**

Every time he tries to install Diablo, he change to drive **A** but it says "invalid directory" and doesn't save anything there, but instead, it suggest the drive **C** (where there is no space left).

Could it be because A is originally for Floppy disk? How could he fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the installer is based off of some ancient technology developed in Blizzard's dark ages and, as you suspected, you cannot install on either a drive lettered A or B.  As noted, this is because these were the floppy or other external media drives from a long time ago, and it simply won't recognize them as a valid install location.

You must change the drive letter to something NOT A-C (D is always a wonderful choice) in order to install Diablo III and commence the looting.

Comment: Thanks, I'll hit him (again) for creating in the directory **A**

Comment: @Michel it could be worse - once I flubbed a Windows install and ended up with the OS on drive I:\ and the data drive as J:\. Real good way to flush out poorly-coded installer programs!

Answer (score 1):

Try subst:

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/subst.mspx?mfr=true

Simply go to a command prompt and type

```
subst d: a:/diablo3
```

Then install to D:.

Once it's installed, move it wherever you actually want it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming his drives are both formatted NTFS, you can try using the mklink command described here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link

I would do that with whatever folder he will be installing into, and then run the installer.

Although a different situation, I use this trick to move games that I already have installed on my HDD onto an SSD without re-installing them.

Effectively, you can make a folder on 1 drive look like it's actually a folder on another drive.  This is done at a very low level in the NTFS filesystem API, so the end-user software doesn't even seem to know.  I was worried this could agitate sensitive applications (i.e. PunkBuster), but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried right clicking on the Diablo III setup file and choosing 'run as administrator'? I had the same issue and 'run as admin..' solved it and it installed just fine.