# Why is Diablo 3 installing slowly on SSD, no installing on drives A: and B:?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've already looked around a bit and found only unrelated stuff.

My setup is a i7 2600k, 8gb ram, 250 gb SSD, 3* 500gb HD.

I first started installing on my SSD, but after 1.5 hours and 5% I stopped the installation and tried restarting it on my other drives. I first tried to drives named a: and b:, but those didn't work because blizzard apparently blocks the use of those. I tried my third HD (7 year old piece of junk) and I've gotten to 40% in 20 minutes.

Anybody know why a SSD with 500mb/s read and write is slower than an old HD? Or why A: and B: can't be used? The SSD works fine the rest of the time.

Comment: do you mean SSD - solid state drive?

Comment: A:\B: may be disallowed because historically they are reserved for removable media. Try aliasing an unused drive letter to one of your HDD's, install there, and when done, you can copy/move the folder to your SSD.

Comment: Are you installing from disk or installing via download? if download; is it already fully downloaded and you are just executing the installation?

Comment: About the drive. This may help you [How can I change the installation directory to drive A?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66392/how-can-i-change-the-installation-directory-to-drive-a)

Comment: user1090190: Yes.
Frantumn: Disk.
Michel: Thanks, but already knew that. Was looking for the reason.
@Wikwocket: Hmm. Kind of odd that something like that would prevent installation. But seems like a reasonable explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4927184224) on blizzard's forums, the installer prevents installing to a directory on the A: and B: drives.

> You can't use the drive letters A or B with the installer as they're
>   not allowed. (reserved for floppy drives)
>
> You'll need to change the drive letter of the drive.

The exact error should be something like

> The folder you selected cannot be used. Please select a different
>   folder.

Luckily, there is an easy way to get around this issue.

1. Close the installer
2. Open a windows command prompt
3. Enter the command `subst Z: B:`
4. Open the installer and install to your Z: drive

Obviously, substitute Z: for any unmapped drive and B: for the drive that you would like to actually install on.

Comment: Sorry for the late marking as answer